# Stop setInterval function executing from loop

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Using CDC(Change Data Capture) I'm displaying count down time in my lightning component. For countdown time I'm using setInterval function of JS, its working fine. 
But on next change of data its displaying both the older and new value. bascially its toggling for both the older value and new value.

Which I guess due to execution of setInterval again.

```
var x = setInterval(function() {

            console.log(">>> intervalToClear... ",intervalToClear);
            console.log(">>> x... ",x);
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            component.set("v.days",days);
            component.set("v.hours",hours);
            component.set("v.minutes",minutes);
            component.set("v.seconds",seconds);


        }, 1000);
```

Comment: did you try to use clearInterval() function?

Comment: yes I tried, but everytime the interval value is getting changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the interval ID in an attribute, and clear the previous if already set:

```
var intervalId = component.get("v.intervalId");
if(intervalId) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
var x = setInterval(function() { /* existing interval function here */ });
component.set("v.intervalId", x);
```